# How to save video into Camera Roll

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can I use this code to save a recorded video in the Camera Roll?

```
Medialibrary.SavePictureToCameraRoll(fileName, Stream);
```

where `Stream` is photo stream or video stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't save videos in the camera roll from a third party application at the moment. That API can be used just to save pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is. Have you tried it yet?

A quick google's come up with this: 
http://wp.qmatteoq.com/how-to-save-a-picture-captured-with-the-new-cameras-api-in-the-camera-roll-in-windows-phone-8/

Comment: Thanks. Wondering if I take a video and save in ISO. Later, I retrieve the same video from ISO but I want to save it in Camera Roll now. Is this done the same way as the link you included? I Have done it for photo but I am not sure about video.

Comment: You really should ask another question for that